# Comments & file name cause run time error?

Tags: opengl, glut

I am working on a OpenGL glut project. However, strange thing happen. The first is that I notice in the main.cpp, by changing the number of rows of comments, it causes run time error. However, for the same file, I changed its name to niam.cpp and everything works fine!

Have any one encountered any problems like this?
I will not upload the actual codes, because everything in it has been commend out except the several codes to create a simple glut window. And it works fine when I just change the file name.

Comment: if it depends on the file name - what is the filename? Is the very simple glut example compiling? What is the error?

Comment: The filename is simply main.cpp. The very simple glut do compile. But when I tried to run it, it gives a runtime error says access violation.

Comment: Could it be a problem with make and that the file was not rebuild, until you renamed it, and before it had an programming error causing this violation? Wich IDE/OS/Compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> The first is that I notice in the main.cpp, by changing the number of rows of comments, it causes run time error.

What exactly did you change? Please post some source code.

> However, for the same file, I changed its name to niam.cpp and everything works fine!

In C and C++ the compilation unit source file name doesn't matter at all. It could be anything. All that matters are the symbols defined inside it.

Note that there are many other languages for which this is not the case, i.e. the filename has a strong relation to the contents. But not in C and C++.